# Stop monitor from waking up unnecessarily when running scheduled task .bat

Tags: windows-10, display, batch-file, cmd.exe, task-scheduler

I run Windows 10. My computer runs 24/7. In my power settings, the monitor is set to go to sleep after after a period of inactivity. This only applies to the monitor, and not the computer. The computer never enters sleep/hibernation.

I run a [nightly Gmail backup script](https://gmail-backup.en.uptodown.com/windows) via command line, contained in a .bat file which is set by Task Scheduler to run at 02:00 every day. The .bat script opens the cmd prompt window while it runs, and closes when it's finished.

The problem is that for some reason, when the task scheduler runs the .bat, the monitor wakes up. Yes - at 02:00 in the morning, the monitor will turn itself on, simply to show the cmd window opening.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Unfortunately when I search for solutions with key words such as "stop/prevent", "task scheduler", "bat[ch] file", "command/cmd prompt", "wake/waking up" and "monitor" - all the results relate to people wishing to run scripts to wake up their computer. I can find no mention of other people with a similar problem, in that the *monitor* is being *undesirably* woken up.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried setting ‘‘Run whether user is logged on or not’’?

Comment: @Scott - That option is set to "Run only when user is logged on". But I'm logged in 24/7 anyway (I'm the only user of my computer). So it's not that - but thanks anyway.

Comment: My thought was that, if it runs when you aren’t logged in, it (probably) won’t display it on the monitor. So, maybe, if you configure it to ‘‘Run whether user is logged on or not’’, it won’t try to use the monitor. I’m just guessing; I’ll let you test it if you care. A related guess: can you configure it to use a different user ID than the one you’re logged in as?

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Wake the Computer to Run This Task" on in the task's 'Conditions' tab, turn it off.

Comment: The computer runs 24/7; waking the computer is not an issue. Why do you believe that this will make a difference? Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks, but "Wake the Computer to Run this Task" is already turned off. Also as stated by @Scott, the computer's running all the time anyway. The matter of concern is the monitor.

Comment: Try this out: https://msfn.org/board/topic/43043-turn-off-monitor-from-a-batch/